# Download the subspecies data using R packages (dismo)

Tags: r, dismo

I would like to use `dismo` (R packages) to download gbif species occurrence data for species distribution analysis.
I have read the guideline and successfully proceeded our analysis in most cases.
I used the code here.

```
gbif("genus","species", geo=FALSE)
```

However, I would like to divided certain subspecies for analysis separately.
Would there be any ways I can do to extract information from certain subspecies?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation of `gbif` and the vignettes of `dismo`, we can append `*` to the species name to get all the variants under that species name. The following example, from the vignettes, downloads all records under *Solanum acaule*.

```
acaule <- gbif("solanum", "acaule*", geo = FALSE)
```

The resulting dataframe, `acaule`, contains 115 variables with about 7000 records. Among these variables, the `scientificName` column contains full names of that records. We can use that column to identify the records related to a certain subspecies.

For example, we can first use the `table` function to see the number of each species name.

```
table(acaule$scientificName)

                             Solanum acaule Bitter 
                                              5608 
                      Solanum acaule subsp. acaule 
                                              1444 
Solanum acaule subsp. punae (Juz.) Hawkes & Hjert. 
                                                14 
           Solanum acaule var. punae (Juz.) Hawkes 
                                                 9 
       Solanum acaule var. subexinterruptum Bitter 
                                                 2 
                        Solanum schreiteri Bukasov 
                                                 2 
                         Solanum uyunense Cárdenas 
                                                 2
```

Now we can subset the dataframe to find the records we want based on the key words in `scientificName`. Suppose we only want records with `subsp.` in its `scientificName`, we can do the following:

```
acaule_sub <- subset(acaule, grepl("subsp.", scientificName, fixed = TRUE))
```

Now `acaule_sub` is a dataframe with 1458 records, which are all the records with a scientific name associated with "subsp.".

Not sure if this is what you need, but I hope it helps!